# Получить счетчики производительности

Tags: c#, производительность, счетчики, мониторинг

Мне необходимо получить данные системы как в мониторинге ресурсов Windows. А именно работу каждого процесса с файлами и статистику. Данные из верхней таблице нашел через `GetPidIoCounters` и структуру `IO_COUNTERS` а вот данные из нижней сетки не получается.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вам нужен класс PerfomanceCounter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 3):

1) Через WMI, класс [Win32_Process](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394372(v=vs.85).aspx), как с ним работать написано [тут](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12138/Process-Information-and-Notifications-using-WMI) и [тут](http://scriptcoding.ru/2013/08/12/win32-process/)

2) Через [PerformanceCounter](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3008626/application-development/how-to-work-with-performance-counters-in-c.html)

```
void Main()
{
    Process p = Process.GetProcesses()[0];
    PerformanceCounter ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Working Set", p.ProcessName);
    PerformanceCounter cpuCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", p.ProcessName);
    PerformanceCounter privateCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "Private Bytes", p.ProcessName);
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        double ram = ramCounter.NextValue();
        double cpu = cpuCounter.NextValue();
        double privateBytes = privateCounter.NextValue();

        Console.WriteLine("RAM: "+(ram/1024/1024)+" MB; CPU: "+(cpu)+" %; " + privateBytes/1024/1024 + " MB");
    }
}
```

Comment: а можно без WMI ? средствами C# или WIN API - шными функциями?

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужен класс [PerfomanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.performancecounter(v=vs.110).aspx):

Примерно так будет:

```
foreach(var process in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    PerformanceCounter pcRead = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "IO Write Bytes/sec", process.ProcessName);
    PerformanceCounter pcWrite = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "IO Read Bytes/sec", process.ProcessName);
    Console.WriteLine($"Read: {pcRead.NextValue()} + %");
    Console.WriteLine($"Write: {pcWrite.NextValue()} + %");
}
```

[Пример описание использования](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/faber/2014/11/20/tracking-windows-performance-counters-by-application/)

[Список категорий для процессов](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms804621.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Первая строка выдает  ошибку **Could not locate Performance Counter with specified category name 'Process', counter name 'Avg. Disk sec/Read'.** Получается что в категории Process нельзя посмотреть счетчик Avg. Disk sec/Read . можно ли где то посмотреть все счетчики относящиеся к категории?

Comment: @gregor, поправил ответ)

Comment: да. получилось. я вывел все счетчики по категории и нашел. Но я не могу понять как получить это для каждого файла этого процесса ?  как в мониторинге ресурсов на моем скрине

Comment: посмотрите это https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724509%28VS.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396
 возможно поможет

Comment: для того, чтобы детектить какие файлы открытым процессом можно глянуть это http://vmccontroller.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/47386#195318